# Ubuntu fails to boot properly after RAM upgrade

Tags: ram

I have a Optiplex 3070 with a i5-9500 processor. It has 8Gb ddr4 on board, but I wanted an ugrade to 16Gb RAM. I installed two sticks of HyperX fury 8Gb DDR4 2666Ghz. After rebooting my screen went al funny and all I see is lines and strange colours. It also bootloops...When is install the older RAM everything is back to normal.
I have UBUNTU 22.04.3 installed as an OS. The BIOS is updated and recognizes the RAM.
Is there something I can do about it to get these sticks working or should I try to find other sticks of RAM?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the Ubuntu with the newer RAM??

Comment: I didn't. I thought about it, but I can't see what I am doing on my screen.

Comment: Boot into Memory Test utility `memtest86+` which comes default with Ubuntu or from Ubuntu live CD. It's on the Grub boot screen (hold down `shift` during boot if it does not show already. Run it for several hours or better still overnight to see if the RAM is giving any errors.

Comment: It probably don't work. Dell doesn't support XMP I found out after digging deeper and deeper.. I think about selling them again and buy sticks without xmp. But thank you or the answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual artifacts and boot loops are strong signs that the new RAM is not working properly. The two sticks of 8 GB DDR4 RAM that you bought seem to be incompatible with your motherboard or CPU. Reinstalling Ubuntu will not fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected it wouldn't work. Dell doesn't support XMP. I didn't know. Lesson learned for me. I will be looking for other ones that do match up with my motherboard.

Comment: Thqnks for the help!